# Model first in entity framework vs2010, create new database

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

I am very new to entity framework just started learning. I have been following a MCTS book to learn entity framework.

I have VS2010, sql server 2008 both of them are express editions. I have created a .edmx file in my project. Described two entities. Now I click generate database from model option, from the context menu by right clicking in the diagram. A generate database wizrd opens, now I choose new.

I don't see any option here to connect to my sql server instance?
However, I see only:

1. Microsoft sql server database file.
2. microsoft sql server compact 3.5.

My objective is to create a new database and create those two entities as tables, in my local sql server instance.

Any help shall be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Its Model first, not code first. Update your title.

Comment: You need to select Microsoft SQL Server Database File.

Comment: @FaisalHafeez Don't You think by selecting Microsoft Database file, I will end up creating a new mdf or sdf local file in my application? But I want to create a new database in my local sql server instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hit and trials I finally come to conclusion that this feature is not available in VS2010 express edition, since I was easily able to do this in vs2010 professional edition.